# Azure SQL Database table level backup and restore

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I need to set up a monthly database update process for my testing database in Azure SQL Database. However, I want to exclude specific large tables during this update because they don't change frequently, and it would save resources. Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this?

I was thinking that if I can make a backup of production and then restore the backup minus the 2 big tables, but I am not sure how to do that or if it's possible. I was wondering if there are any tools that can maybe assist and if there are any pitfalls to watch out for.

Comment: What do you mean by "save resources"? Azure SQL already comes with automatic backup. For this native backup you can't do table specific backups, you can only specify retention. It's quicker easier to actually do a full restore than it is to cook up some process that only restores certain tables

Answer (score 0):

You can export the database as a bacpac using [SqlPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-export?view=sql-server-ver16) and specify that only a subset of the tables will be exported to an Azure Storage Account. For example:

```
.\sqlpackage.exe `
    /a:Export `
    /scs:"Data Source=$($ServerName);Initial Catalog=$($SourceDbName);User ID=my_user;Password=my_password" `
    /tf:$BacPacFileName `
    /p:TableData=[dbo].[Table1] /p:TableData=[dbo].[Table2]
```

You can also restore a full database bacpac and simply drop the two big tables after the import has finished. You can create a scheduled task using Azure Automation, if needed.